App Scan Recommended Prompt after migration from FCM to FCM V1
I'm using notification hub on azure to send notifications from server to mobile application. Recently, I have migrated my application from fcm to fcm v1.
I have created a new project for the fcm v1 and used the google-services.json of the new project into application.
The previous project is being used for development environment and the new account is being used for production.
Now, I wanted my customers to upgrade the applications to latest one. But after testing, I found out that there is a prompt of App Scan Recommended while installing the latest APK.
This prompt is occurring randomly i.e. not on every installation.
Is there any google update which is causing this issue?
Note: My application is not on google playstore but my customers not received a single prompt in past. This is happening now after migration.
Project settings
App Scan Recommended
Note: my application contains single .jks file and I am using SHA1 of this file for development and SHA256 for production.
I tried different solution on the internet but nothing is working.

This part of a security check for apps which are not part of Play Store. As they are not checked when uploaded to Play Console so they do some tests while installing.
If app is legal and follows rules then no need to worry.
Read more here

So, this is normal and expected behavior?

And why this prompt was not occurring in past then?

Yes its part of new security measures. Read the document attached in the answer for full details

But this document shows Last updated at 2019-11-12 UTC.
And we are getting this prompt since last week after migration.

Malware, Mobile Unwanted Software (MUwS) etc parts are updated recently
